# Re-register a background task uwp

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, uwp, background-task

Omg I ask 100 questions here, but I always get stuck on difficult stuff I can't google an answer to..

I want to use my background task to run a method once a day at a specific time.

I have this when I register the task:

```
public async void RegisterBackgroundTask()
{
    var taskRegistered = false;
    var TaskName = "TimeTriggeredTask";

    foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
    {
        if (task.Value.Name == TaskName)
        {
            taskRegistered = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    var tommorowMidnight = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
    var timeTilMidnight = tommorowMidnight - DateTime.Now;
    var minutesTilMidnight = (uint)timeTilMidnight.TotalMinutes;
    if (!taskRegistered)
    {
        var task = RegisterBackgroundTask("Tasks.TaskBuilder",
        "TimeTriggeredTask",
        new TimeTrigger(minutesTilMidnight, true),
        new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable));
        await task;
        CheckPremieres();

    }

}
```

Now I want to re-register the task when it Run, but with `new TimeTrigger(60*24, false),` insted. I have tried to do this in BackgroundTask Project but first I delete the first Task.

So is there a better way of running a Background Task once a day at 00:00. I have also thought about not having a Trigger and just use a If-statement that checks if the time is 00:00..

Comment: No one? Mabey this is not posible? Becuse i cant find awnsers on google like i said and no awnser

Comment: Your code didn't work or you ask for a better solution ?

Comment: A solution that work.. :), now if lets say a user starts the app for the first time and the Clock is 23:00 then the time will be 1h.. so the Task will run every 1h.. i must reset the Task with the new time 60*24.. or if there is a better way.. do that.. :)

Comment: The questions is how can I re-register the Task when the Task Run? Or is there a Trigger I can use that fires the Task every day at 00:00??